# magnitude of magnetic anomalies (Earth and Mars)

Tags: mars, earth, magnetic-field

I've been looking for the magnitude of highest and lowest magnetic anomalies on Earth and Mars (mapped by spacecraft in low orbit), by searching online I couldn't really find a numerical value. From pictures of models of magnetic anomalies, I found that the values on the scale seem to be different from each other. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: It may be hard to answer this question because the magnitude of [Magnetic anomalies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_anomaly) depends on the spatial size of the fluctuation and the distance you are from the surface. A large but fairly local anomaly might be invisible from an orbiting satellite because on the surface you may be only kilometers or less from the anomaly but you're 6000 kilometers away from the source of Earth's *much stronger* main dipole field. I was going to write that as a (fairly unhelpful) answer and show some math, but you may want to adjust your question first.

Comment: To do an apples-to-apples comparison, perhaps you can narrow this down to magnetic fields mapped by spacecraft in low orbit?

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm looking for, sorry for the question not being clear enough